# Javascript: How to check if array of object has one and only one item with given value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I know that in Javascript I can use `.some` or `.every` on arrays to check if they have atleast one item or every item that passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Here is some examples:

```
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(x => x > 10);  // false
[12, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(x => x > 10); // true

[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(x => x >= 10); // false
[12, 54, 18, 130, 44].every(x => x >= 10); // true
```

I'm looking for checking if an array has "one and only one" item that passes the given function.
I would like to have some method like the following:

```
[12, 5, 12, 13, 4].oneAndOnlyOne(x => x >= 10); // false
[2, 11, 6, 1, 4].oneAndOnlyOne(x => x >= 10); // true
```

Do you know any new ECMA Script 6 way or any easy/quick way, even using `lodash`, to check if in array there is one and one only occurrence of item that has certain values?

Comment: `[...].filter(x => x > 10).length === 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could reach desired result using `Array#filter`.

```js
const oneAndOnlyOne = arr => arr.filter(v => v >= 10).length == 1;

console.log(oneAndOnlyOne([12, 5, 12, 13, 4]));
console.log(oneAndOnlyOne([2, 11, 6, 1, 4]));
```

Comment: This will apply the function to every element in the array, which could theoretically be a problem is there are a lot of elements, or if the function is expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient solution is the simple loop:

```
function findOne(arr) {
  var foundOne = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if(arr[i] > 10)
      if(foundOne) return false;
      else foundOne = true;
  }
  return foundOne;
}
```

There are some tools out there that already do this. Like [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#countBy) for instance. You can just find one that suits you.

Answer (score 1):

Slice the array at the point the first match is found, then search in the remaining part of the array, as in

```js
function oneAndOnlyOne(arr, fn) {
  const pos = arr.findIndex(fn);
  return pos >= 0 && !arr.slice(pos + 1).find(fn);
}

const tests = [[12, 5, 12, 13, 4], [2, 11, 6, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3]];
  
for (const test of tests) 
  console.log(String(test), oneAndOnlyOne(test, x => x >= 10));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with `filter` and array length match with `1` .And use callback method added with `Array.prototype.oneAndOnlyOne`

```js
Array.prototype.oneAndOnlyOne=function(callback){
  return this.filter(callback).length == 1
}

console.log([12, 11, 6, 1, 4].oneAndOnlyOne(x=> x >= 10)) // false
console.log([2, 11, 6, 1, 4].oneAndOnlyOne(x=> x >= 10)) // true
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a function to your array (since it is an object after all):

```
var arr = [30];
arr.oneAndOnlyOne = function(numToCheck) { 
    return this.filter(function(x) {
        return x >= numToCheck
    }).length === 1
}

arr.oneAndOnlyOne(30); //true
arr.push(30);
arr.oneAndOnlyOne(30); //false
```